# How to write Russian characters to file with cffile

Tags: coldfusion, io, character-encoding, coldfusion-10

I have a string I need to write to create an XML file.  The string has Russian characters in it, which I can `cfoutput` to the page no problem, but when I write the file with `cffile`, those characters return with a ?.  I tried changing the `charset` to the following with no success:

- windows-1252
- iso-8859-1
- cp1251
- cp866

I'm sure the `charset` is the problem here.  Any suggestions?

Here is one of the strings in question:  Другие

I'm running ColdFusion 10 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 System.

Comment: What are russian characters?

Comment: Non utf-8 characters - ABCD, etc.  It's a different alphabet and character set altogether.  See the line above _Here is one of the...._

Comment: Where do the characters come from? A DB? How sure are you, they are present correctly and not already broken when calling CFFILE?

Comment: As fare as I know UTF-8 has all the characters used on the Earth in any language.

Comment: They're ingested from an excel document with `cfspreadsheet`.  When I `cfdump` the spreadsheet query I see the Cyrillic characters correctly, also when I print the string to the page with `cfoutput` it shows up correctly, but when I try to write that string to a file, that's where I run into problems.

Comment: Set the `charset = "utf-8"` when writting to the file.

Comment: I could have sworn I'd tried that first.  That works, as well as wrapping the string in `charsetdecode`.  Thanks for the help all.

Comment: UTF-8 is the correct encoding

Comment: Seconded what @GerryGurevich says. One uses UTF-8 for Cyrillic. The issue is that ColdFusion 8's `<cffile>` doesn't correctly write UTF-8-encoded text. I shall try to google the answer, as I don't have the code to hand. This is not an uncommon situation though.

Comment: js1983 - You guys already figured out the answer, so one of you should post it as such :)  @MaxZoom said [*"Set the charset = "utf-8" when writing to the file."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042172/how-to-write-russian-characters-to-file-with-cffile-in-coldfusion-8#comment46325126_29042172) and you mentioned [using charsetDecode to get the binary and writing the *bytes* with charset = "utf-8"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042172/how-to-write-russian-characters-to-file-with-cffile-in-coldfusion-8#comment46325294_29042172).  Obviously whatever reads the file should use utf8 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the charset = "utf-8" when writing to the file

Comment: Did you need to do anything else for CF8, or was @MaxZoom's answer sufficient? FWIW, it works fine with CF10 using an .xlsx file source.

Comment: I edited my post as it was actually CF10 I was using, not CF8.  The source wasn't the problem, it was the writing to a file that was the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did not think the source file was the issue. Just mentioning what tests I ran for comparison.  *it was actually CF10 I was using* Haha, it did not register, but of course using cfspreadsheet means you must be running at least CF9+. Silly me. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I have had pageencoding problems in the past.  Try `<cfprocessingDirective pageencoding="utf-8">`  Make sure you put it every template in the operation.  Putting it in application.cfm or application.cfc may not be sufficient.

Comment: This only effects content of the actual source code file. It does not impact how data is handled. It's *unlikely* the text being written to file is in the source code file?

Comment: @AdamCameron Good call.  I remember now.  I was doing some multilingual stuff directly in a webpage a number of years back.  Please don't judge :-)

Comment: Haha Gerry. I might be a lot of things, but I try not to be judgemental. We've all done / needed to do that anyhow.